# Development board for DASH7

Tags: microcontrollers

Has anyone experimented with DASH7? I am searching for a development board, which is proven to work with the DASH7 stack in the 433/868 MHz bands.

There are, of course, the official development kits, such as the [WizziKit](http://wizzilab.com/product/wizzikit-dash7-1-x), but they are expensive.

Comment: Hello all, please keep comments kind and welcoming.  See [the blog post here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) for more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also find kits here:

https://www.liquibit.be/our_product.html

https://sub-iot.github.io/Sub-IoT-Stack/blog/2017/08/22/new-devkit/

https://jitter.nl/design/

LiQuibit is very effective in developing DASH7 solutions.